# Bootstrap - How to split and align dropdown li list in two columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap - How to split dropdown ul>li list in two columns ?

i am trying to split the ul>li in two columns so that one will align to left ad other will align to right.

i am doing it like this

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">big button</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu text-left">
    <li><a href="#">full name must align to left <span class="text-right">short name - align to right</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">left <span class="text-right">right</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">left<span class="text-right">right</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">full name must align to left <span class="text-right">short name - align to right</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W55vP/

but its all going to left.
so how can i split the ul>li> hyperlink in to two columns so that half part aligns left and othe rhalf part aligns right

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/W55vP/1/?

Comment: yes, but left and right parts are not on the same line .

Comment: and why does right item hides when i mouse hover on left item ?

Comment: is this something like this http://jsfiddle.net/W55vP/2/

Comment: if width size of the box get increased to 500px. it would be look like something http://jsfiddle.net/W55vP/3/

Comment: @MaNKuR still the left item and right are on new line , how can i get them on the same line ?

Comment: not sure if you wanted something like this
http://jsfiddle.net/W55vP/4/  you can decorate rest of the style

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, check the link below:

- [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vishalj/6LGUm/)

**HTML**:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Multicolumn</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <ul>
          <li><a>one</a></li>
          <li>two</li>
          <li>three</li>
          <li>four</li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
          <li>five</li>
          <li>six</li>
          <li>seven</li>
      </ul>
      <ul><li>eight</li>
          </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
.dropdown-menu ul {
    float: left;
}

.dropdown-menu ul:first-of-type {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding-right:20px
}
```